# 行移動を実現するコード

Tags: bash, vim

テキストエディターを作りたいのですが、カーソル位置を矢印キーで操作できるようにしたいです。どのようなコードを書けばいいのか分かりません。

今のところ、以下のようなコードです。

```bash
#!/bin/bash

Add_Write(){
    printf %s "FileName:"
    read -r FN
    FN=$(echo "$FN" | sed "s/[￥\/\\:*?\"<>│]//g")
    echo "Loading..."
    tput smcup
    clear
    content=()
    for ((i=0;;i++)); do
        printf %s "$i>"
        read -r row
        case $row in
            "#exit"|"#quit"|"#QUIT"|"#EXIT")
                echo "Where do you want to save it?"
                read -r save_location
                for row in "${content[@]}"; do
                    echo -e "$row" >> "$save_location/$FN.txt"
                done
                tput rmcup
                break
                exit 0
                ;;
        esac
        content["$i"]="$row"
    done
}

Over_Write(){
    printf %s "FileName:"
    read -r FN
    FN=$(echo "$FN" | sed "s/[￥\/\\:*?\"<>│]//g")
    echo "Loading..."
    tput smcup
    clear
    content=()
    for ((i=0;;i++)); do
        printf %s "$i>"
        read -r row
        case $row in
            "#exit"|"#quit"|"#QUIT"|"#EXIT")
                echo "Where do you want to save it?"
                read -r save_location
                for row in "${content[@]}"; do
                    echo -e "$row" > "$save_location/$FN.txt"
                done
                tput rmcup
                break
                exit 0
                ;;
        esac
        content["$i"]="$row"
    done
}

printf %s "File: Over Write or Add Write [O/A]"
read -r input
if [ "$input" = "O" ] || [ "$input" = "o" ]; then
    Over_Write
elif [ "$input" = "A" ] || [ "$input" = "a" ]; then
    Add_Write
fi
```

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、`Over_Write()` 関数内の `for row in "${content[@]}"; do echo -e "$row" > "$save_location/$FN.txt"; done` の部分が追記になっていないので最終行だけが保存されることになります。for ループを実行する前に保存するファイルを truncate してから追記する(`>>`)様にするとよいかと。

Comment: 参考までに、[hanslub42/rlwrap: A readline wrapper](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) を利用すれば、スクリプトはそのままで行編集機能やヒストリー機能を追加することができます。